# Calculating Overlapping time-span count in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: concurrency, count, sql-server-2008-r2, timespan, overlapping

I need to get concurrency count in SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a provider who will for a date will supervise certain records, I need to get count for overlapping times. e.g

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @Concurrency Table
    (
      [ConcurrencyTimeID] BigInt,
      [SupervisingProviderID] Int,
      [SupervisingProviderFirstName] Varchar(50),
      [SupervisingProviderLastName] Varchar(50),
      [DateOfService] DateTime,
      [PatientFirstName] Varchar(50),
      [PatientLastName] Varchar(50),
      [StartTime] Time,
      [StopTime] Time,
      [DStartTime] DateTime,
      [DStopTime] DateTime,
      [IsNextDay] Bit
    )

INSERT  INTO @Concurrency
    (
      [ConcurrencyTimeID],
      [SupervisingProviderID],
      [SupervisingProviderFirstName],
      [SupervisingProviderLastName],
      [DateOfService],
      [PatientFirstName],
      [PatientLastName],
      [StartTime],
      [StopTime],
      [IsNextDay]
    )
    SELECT  25, 4, 'hardik', 'Patel', '05/30/2016', 'a', 'a', '8:00:00 PM', '11:00:00 PM', 0
    UNION ALL SELECT  25, 4, 'hardik', 'Patel', '05/30/2016', 'b', 'b', '8:30:00 PM', '9:30:00 PM', 0
    UNION ALL SELECT  25, 4, 'hardik', 'Patel', '05/30/2016', 'c', 'c', '9:00:00 PM', '11:30:00 PM', 0
    UNION ALL SELECT  25, 4, 'hardik', 'Patel', '05/30/2016', 'd', 'd', '10:00:00 PM', '2:00:00 AM', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT  25, 4, 'hardik', 'Patel', '05/31/2016', 'e', 'e', '1:00:00 AM', '3:00:00 AM', 0
    UNION ALL SELECT  25, 4, 'hardik', 'Patel', '05/31/2016', 'f', 'f', '2:30:00 AM', '3:30:00 AM', 0

    UPDATE  @Concurrency
    SET     [DStartTime] = ( Convert(Varchar, [c].[DateOfService], 112) + Cast([c].[StartTime] AS DateTime) ),
        [DStopTime] = CASE WHEN [c].[IsNextDay] = 1 THEN ( Convert(Varchar, [c].[DateOfService], 112) + Cast('23:59' AS DateTime) )
                           ELSE ( Convert(Varchar, [c].[DateOfService], 112) + Cast([c].[StopTime] AS DateTime) )
                      END
    FROM    @Concurrency AS [c]
```

My query:

```
SELECT  [c].[SupervisingProviderID],
        [ca].[Ccount]
FROM    @Concurrency AS [c]
        CROSS APPLY (
                      SELECT    [Ccount] = Count(*)
                      FROM      @Concurrency AS [c2]
                      WHERE     [c].[DateOfService] = [c2].[DateOfService]
                                AND [c].[SupervisingProviderID] = [c2].[SupervisingProviderID]
                                AND [c].[DStartTime] <= [c2].[DStopTime]
                                AND [c2].[DStartTime] <= [c].[DStopTime]
                    ) AS ca
```

Expected Result

[image: Result]

At present I am getting **Concurrency = 4** for **Patient - A**. Can anyone help me get what am I doing wrong?